# Importing data using NService Bus

Tags: import, nservicebus, cqrs, saga

Using NService Bus. 2.00.19 (with MSMQ and SQL 2008)
We want to import data into our system.
The files could be quite large so we have Background Processor that will read a message from the Bus. This could take an hour to process.

Have other people done this? Is a Saga the best way forward?

Comment: Is the data in the message?  If so you will run into a limitation until the data bus is implemented in 3.0.

Comment: The data isn't in the message. It holds a file location. The handler then gets the file (xml) and updates the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just a single message, then you might not need a saga. That being said, you may find it useful to have the endpoint reading off of the file send multiple messages each one containing one "row", and you might then find some use for a saga to track progress.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We did start to go down the route but the imports needs to be atomic. We didn't want some of the "row" commands to succeed and other fail.

Comment: It would be pretty difficult for the import of this very large file to be atomic anyway.  I would still go with individual row commands as you could gain a lot of benefits from parallel processing this way.  You then use your error queue to deal with any failed rows.  To get more general atomicity from the file as a whole, you could do the import row by row into a temp table, using a saga to track how many rows have completed successfully, and when all are complete, do a SQL MERGE or outright table rename.